# How can I install kubectx on Ubuntu Linux 20.04?

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes

I would like to install kubectx on Ubuntu 20.04. I couldn't find any info on how to do it. Any comment is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The documentation for the installation of kubens and kubectx can be found here.
https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx#installation

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This package contains in `deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian buster main` repo which is not available in ubuntu.

First you need to do add this to `/etc/apt/sources.list` like below

```
#for kubectlx
deb [trusted=yes] http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian buster main
```

Then run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then you can install using this cmd.

```
sudo apt install kubectx
```

Comment: I was trying to follow the instructions listed on other sites  , which just mention running  `sudo apt install kubectx` ... but this would result in **"package not found"** error , thanks for pointing out that the **sources.list** file needs to be edited as well. This is good stuff

Comment: Remember to check which version of debian your version of ubuntu is based on. You migth want to replace "buster" with a different release. https://askubuntu.com/questions/445487/what-debian-version-are-the-different-ubuntu-versions-based-on/445496#445496

Comment: @MattJanssen look at the comment from Gaz

Comment: In case you encounter public key error during `sudo apt update`, you can fix it by using the solution provided here: https://askubuntu.com/a/943548/544918

Answer (score 13):

The following steps worked for me;

1. sudo apt-get update
2. sudo git clone https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx /usr/local/kubectx
3. sudo ln -s /usr/local/kubectx/kubectx /usr/local/bin/kubectx
4. sudo ln -s /usr/local/kubectx/kubens /usr/local/bin/kubens
5. Enter **kubens** in your console and you should be able to see your namespaces

Comment: Don't forget about the completions, e.g. for zsh: `sudo ln -s /usr/local/kubectx/completion/*.zsh /usr/share/zsh/vendor-completions`

Answer (score 11):

There is a kubectx snap package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu:

```
sudo snap install kubectx --classic
```

Answer (score 4):

I successfully installed `ctx` and `ns` as kubectl plugin using [Krew](https://krew.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user-guide/setup/install/).

```
kubectl krew install ctx
kubectl krew install ns
```

There's one minor catch. You won't use the commands like this:

```
kubectx
kubens
```

But rather like this:

```
kubectl ctx
kubectl ns
```

Answer (score 1):

To install kubectx without having to edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

[Snapcraft - Install kubectx on Ubuntu](https://snapcraft.io/install/kubectx/ubuntu)

If `snapd` is not enabled:

**Install Snapd**

1. `sudo apt update`
2. `sudo apt install snapd`

---

With `snapd` enabled:

**Install `kubectx`**

1. `sudo snap install kubectx`

Answer (score 0):

As cdev pointed, the debian package is available. Downloading only the package and install it locally works for me

```
wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/k/kubectx/kubectx_0.9.3-1_all.deb

sudo dpkg -i kubectx_0.9.3-1_all.deb
```

Answer (score -1):

You can install kubectx using *brew* in Ubuntu. Just run the following command:

```
brew install kubectx
```

Comment: op is looking for Linux/Ubuntu instructions - brew is most common for Mac.  Might want to edit your answer to acknowledge they might have to install brew on Linux to use your suggestion.

Answer (score -4):

This command should work:

```
sudo apt install kubectx
```

If you want find completely install kubectx guide, you need to go to [this github page](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx/blob/master/README.md#installation). You can use an installation for Debian. APT stands for Advanced Package Tool. It is a set of core tools inside Debian and Ubuntu Linux system. You can use the **apt command** to install apps, delete or remove apps, keep Ubuntu/Debian server up to date and more. You can read more about it [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-lts-debian-linux-apt-command-examples/).

It is possible that you should add the package `deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian buster main` before you install `kubectx` in the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` and then run `sudo apt-get update`. After that installation should work without problems.